# How to decide whether the default EKCalendar 'Calendar' can be hidden?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, calendar, eventkit

I'm writing an app that deals with calendars. In the app I'm displaying a list of all available calendars for the user to enable or disable. I'm *not* using the `EventKitUI` framework for purposes of my own design and UI.

I get a neat list of calendars by polling the `calendars` property of an `EKEventStore` object. On my device, however, there's an `EKCalendar` object in that list that is *not* shown by the `EKEventKitUI`. This is a description of the object in the debugger:

```
EKCalendar <0xcea6b60> {title = Agenda; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #711A76;}
```

I'm running my iPhone in Dutch, which is why the title is 'Agenda' and not 'Calendar', but if you run the iPhone in English that's what you'll see. It looks like this is iOS' default calendar, but since I have all my calendars set up to sync with iCloud, it's disabled for the built in calendar apps. I want to disable it in my own app too, but I don't know how.

From looking at [the properties of `EKCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) I cannot discern one for deciding which calendar I should 'hide'. There's the `type` property that is 'Local' for this default calendar, but if someone is not using iCloud I imagine all the calendars are of a local type. `subscription` is not it either, nor is `allowsContentModifications`. I've seen [examples of people hiding the default calendar based on it's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535501/array-of-calendars), but as you can see, the title is localized and thus very impractical, that just feels wrong.

**What's the trick to decide which calendar is the default calendar and whether to hide it or not, in order to parallel the list of calendars that your regular iCal/Calendar app displays?**

***EDIT:*** Although the question was marked as answered, the answer contains a big "no, you can't". I've solved this issue for my users by adding a settings panel switch to 'hide local calendars', but it's a very, very unelegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question in bold, there isn't a magic property you can use to determine if a calendar should be hidden or displayed.

However, if your theory is correct about the Calendar app hiding the "local" calendar if other calendar types are available (iCloud/MobileMe, Exchange, CalDAV, etc), then you can mirror its logic in your code using the `EKSource` array in `EKEventStore`

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

for (EKSource *source in store.sources)
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeExchange || source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV)
    {
        //Your custom logic here to determine if the local cal should be hidden.
        break;
    }
```

You can find the full list of EKSourceType constants here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKSourceClassRef/Reference/Reference.html